# How to push bare repo branches to another remote?

Tags: git

I'm using the decentralized workflow (Central + Fork). On occasion, I'd like to fast-forward all of my remote branches on my fork with the latest changes from their corresponding branches on the central repository.

I've created a second clone of my central repository that is just a bare version. With a single `git push` command, is it possible to push all branches to the fork? I know wildcards can be used in push, but I haven't been able to get it to work. For example, I tried this (I have two remotes on my bare repo, 'upstream' and 'origin'; origin points to my fork, and upstream is the central repo:

```
git push origin refs/remotes/upstream/*:refs/heads/*
```

I still find git's refspec confusing. Specifically, I'm not sure what namespaces are for what. I'm assuming all remote branches are stored under `refs/heads/*`.

Comment: FYI, `git push origin refs/remotes/upstream/*:refs/heads/*` ought to work. Did you forget to fetch from the `upstream` repo first? Also, you don't need a local bare repo to do this push, you could have done this from a non-bare repo as well.

Comment: So myself and a few other folks undeleted this question because it's not an *exact* duplicate, as far as I can tell, and plus I spent my time answering it `:P` If you want to delete it again, I'll let it slide, but if my answer solved your problem or you found it helpful, please consider accepting and/or upvoting it instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use

```
git push <fork> --all
```

to push all branch references under `.git/refs/heads/` to the other remote.

### Documentation

From the [git-scm documentation for `git push`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) (truncated to relevant options):

> ```
> git push [--all | --mirror | --tags] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
>
> --all
> ```
>
> Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under `refs/heads/` be pushed.

### Your Original Command Should Have Worked

FYI, your original command

```
git push origin refs/remotes/upstream/*:refs/heads/*
```

should have worked as well, so I'm not sure what went wrong in your case.

### Refspecs Explained

According to you,

> I still find git's refspec confusing. Specifically, I'm not sure what namespaces are for what. I'm assuming all remote branches are stored under `refs/heads/*`.

So here's the deal with refspecs of the form

```
<source>:<destination>
```

1. All Git repos share the same reference directory structure under their `.git/refs/` directory.

   - Every repo stores local branches (relative to *itself*) under `refs/heads/`.
   - Every repo stores remote-tracking branches (relative to *itself*) under `refs/remotes/<remote>/`.
   - Other references can also be stored under `refs/`, including, but not limited to, `refs/tags/`, but I won't go into details about those. You can also create your own reference directories under `refs/`; GitHub, for example, stores pull requests on remotes under `refs/pulls/<request-number>/`.
2. References on each side of the colon `:` ***are relative*** to the repo represented by that side of the refspec. Pretend that each side of the colon is prepended with the repo on that side.

   **For illustration purposes**, I'll add `[source]/` and `[destination]/` to the refspec examples below, even though that that's not actually the correct syntax for them.

   So, for example, if you wanted to push your local branches to a remote, you need to push them ***to the remote's local branches***. You can use a refspec like this:

   ```
   git push <remote> [source]/refs/heads/*:[destination]/refs/heads/*
   ```

   In the above case, you can also omit the `:refs/heads/*`, since omitting `:<destination>` causes Git to replace that side with the same references used on the `<source>` side:

   ```
   git push <remote> refs/heads/*
   ```

   Now lets say that you wanted to push your local **remote-tracking branches** to a special "namespaced" folder on your remote called `refs/special/`. Then you use the following:

   ```
   git push <remote> \
   [source]/refs/remotes/<pick-a-remote>/*:[destination]/refs/special/*
   ```

Comment: I initially deleted my question because I did not ask the *right* question (in my mind). I did it as quick as possible to avoid wasting anyone else's time. Having said that, `git push <fork> --all` won't work, right? Because it requires me to have all of upstream's branches checked out as local branches I believe.

Comment: @RobertDailey that's true, but as I pointed out, your original refspec should've worked instead in that case.

Comment: @RobertDailey actually, the repo that you were trying to push from, was that bare? Because if it was, all the branches are located under `refs/head/` anyways, in which case `git push --all` ***does work***.

Comment: sorry for the disparity :-) ... I was thinking of a non-bare (which I normally work out on in a day to day basis). The only reason I had a bare clone is for the syncing to my fork. But since you said the initial push I was trying to do should work, that's great.

The only piece that made my question incomplete was that I wanted it to remove branches on the fork that were removed in upstream. But there is no way for git to know if a branch on origin was something unique I pushed or if it is orphaned with respect to upstream. So I do that part by hand.

Comment: I don't know why my initial push wasn't working, but it does work now. I think maybe I was doing something wrong without realizing it. But it does work. Thanks for your help, and especially love your explanation of refspec. The official refspec docs do not explain some of the details you've outlined!

Comment: @RobertDailey "*The only piece that made my question incomplete was that I wanted it to remove branches on the fork that were removed in upstream. But there is no way for git to know if a branch on origin was something unique I pushed or if it is orphaned with respect to upstream. So I do that part by hand.*" I think I can actually fix that for you so that you *don't have to* do it by hand, but I'll need to do some tests first, I'll get back to you in a few days.

Comment: @RobertDailey FYI, `git push` has a `--prune` option, but I'm not sure if it will work in this situation (not until I test it later first)...but if you want to try it out yourself first, make a few extra test clones to try it out on.